# Why does C# DateTime not match SQLServer DateTime?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, date-formatting

With this code:

```
private void ReadData(String _unit, String _member, DateTime _dateBegin, 
    DateTime _dateEnd)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtFillRateResults =
            SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable("sp_CRP_FillRate2",
            CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Unit", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = _unit },
                new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Member", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = _member },
                new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@BegDate", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = _dateBegin },
                new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EndDate", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = _dateEnd }
        );
```

...passing C# DateTime.Date values like so:

```
frpg.GeneratePackets(clbCheckedUnitItems, clbCheckedMembersItems,   
    dateTimePickerFrom.Value.Date, dateTimePickerTo.Value.Date);
. . .
public void GeneratePackets(CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection selectedUnits, CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection selectedMembers, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRowView drvu in selectedUnits)
        {
                . . .
                foreach (DataRowView drvm in selectedMembers)
                {
                    ReadData(unit, shortMemberName, from, to);
                    . . .
```

...it doesn't crash, but I get no records returned. It works no better if I change the args from DateTime.Value.Date to DateTime.Value like so:

```
frpg.GeneratePackets(clbCheckedUnitItems, clbCheckedMembersItems,  
    dateTimePickerFrom.Value, dateTimePickerTo.Value);
```

If I convert the dates to YYYMMDD format like this:

```
String dateBegin = FillRateRptConstsAndUtils.GetYYYYMMDD(_dateBegin, true);
String dateEnd = FillRateRptConstsAndUtils.GetYYYYMMDD(_dateEnd, false);
DataTable dtFillRateResults =
            SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable("sp_CRP_FillRate2",
            CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Unit", SqlDbType = 
SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = _unit },
                new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Member", SqlDbType = 
SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = _member },
                new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@BegDate", SqlDbType = 
SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = dateBegin },
                new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EndDate", SqlDbType = 
SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = dateEnd }
        );

public static string GetYYYYMMDD(DateTime rawDate, bool startOfRange)
{
    int year = rawDate.Year;
    int month = rawDate.Month;
    String monthAsStr = month.ToString();
    if (monthAsStr.Length == 1)
    {
        monthAsStr = "0" + monthAsStr;
    }
    var dayVal = startOfRange ? "01" : GetLastDayOfMonth(month, 
year.ToString());
    if (dayVal.Length == 1)
    {
        dayVal = "0" + dayVal;
    }
    return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", year, monthAsStr, dayVal);
}

public static string GetLastDayOfMonth(int monthAsInt, String year)
{
    int yearAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(year);
    DateTime d8 = new DateTime(yearAsInt, monthAsInt, 
DateTime.DaysInMonth(yearAsInt, monthAsInt));
    return d8.Day.ToString();
}
```

...I get, "*Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a DateTime*"

Finally, if I try this (converting the YYYYMMDD string to a DateTime):

```
    DataTable dtFillRateResults =
        SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable("sp_CRP_FillRate2",
    CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Unit", SqlDbType = 
SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = _unit },
        new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Member", SqlDbType = 
SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = _member },
        new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@BegDate", SqlDbType = 
SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateBegin) },
        new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EndDate", SqlDbType = 
SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEnd) }
    );
```

...I get, "*String was not recognized as a valid dateTime*"

So what the helium is going on here? How can I give SQL Server what it wants?

### UPDATE

BTW, ExecuteSQLReturnDataSet() is:

```
private static readonly int EXTENDED_TIMEOUT = 120;

public static DataSet ExecuteSQLReturnDataSet(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(FillRateRptConstsAndUtils.CPSConnStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = EXTENDED_TIMEOUT;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        }

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sqlex.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                var sqlexDetail = String.Format("From ExecuteDataSet(), SQL Exception #{0}{1}Source: {2}{1}Number: {3}{1}State: {4}{1}Class: {5}{1}Server: {6}{1}Message: {7}{1}Procedure: {8}{1}LineNumber: {9}",
                    i + 1, // Users would get the fantods if they saw #0
                    Environment.NewLine,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Source,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Number,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].State,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Class,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Server,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Message,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Procedure,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].LineNumber);
                MessageBox.Show(sqlexDetail);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String exDetail = String.Format(FillRateRptConstsAndUtils.ExceptionFormatString, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show(exDetail);
        }
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's really several questions in here. For the first one as to why you get no rows returned, we need to know what the stored procedure is actually doing and does it return data when you execute it manually?

Comment: Please try to keep the question more specific and remove not relevant code.

Comment: Without knowing the stored procedure being called it's impossible to answer. At first sight the first sample looks good, but what happens inside the stored proc is a mystery so far.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to have carnal knowledge of the SP; in a nutshell, it's simply a matter of "what format will SQL Server accept for DateTime vals"?

Comment: In your first example, you are passing it a date, there is no "format" needed. That is why knowledge of the SP is actually integral to answering the question.

Comment: Also you really need to distil this down to [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This huge wall of text could probably be reduced to a few simple lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
String dateBegin = 
    FillRateRptConstsAndUtils.GetYYYYDashMMDashDD(_dateBegin, true);
String dateEnd =
    FillRateRptConstsAndUtils.GetYYYYDashMMDashDD(_dateEnd, false);
DataTable dtFillRateResults =
    SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable("sp_CRP_FillRate2",
        CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Unit", SqlDbType
= SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = _unit },
        new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Member",
SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = _member },
        new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@BegDate",
SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateBegin) },
        new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EndDate",
SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEnd) }
    );

public static string GetYYYYDashMMDashDD(DateTime rawDate, bool startOfRange)
{
    int year = rawDate.Year;
    int month = rawDate.Month;
    String monthAsStr = month.ToString();
    if (monthAsStr.Length == 1)
    {
        monthAsStr = "0" + monthAsStr;
    }
    var dayVal = startOfRange ? "01" : GetLastDayOfMonth(month, year.ToString());
    if (dayVal.Length == 1)
    {
        dayVal = "0" + dayVal;
    }
    return String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", year, monthAsStr, dayVal);
}
```

IOW, value passed to ConvertToDateTime() must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: This is a poor answer. Why convert from a date to string then back to date again?

Comment: Because it wasn't working as a DateTime.Value or DateTime.Value.Date. That was the crux of the quesiton.

Comment: Well this code changes the dates from the ones passed in to ones that are at the beginning and end of the month, that's why it's working differently. This answer bears no resemblance to the question asked.